# debug_1$6.Debug.extend is not a function when typing npm run build and npm run preivew nuxt

Tags: javascript, proxy, nuxt.js

i have proxy:

```
// proxy: {
// options: {
// target: 'http://example.com:8000',
// changeOrigin: true,
// pathRewrite: {
// '/auth': '/auth',
// '/site-test': '/site-test',
// '/site-prod': '/site-prod',
// },
// pathFilter: [
// '/auth',
// '/site-test',
// '/site-prod'
// ]
// }
// },
```

i use nuxt-proxy dependency. It works fine in dev mode but when i try write

```
npm run build
npm run preview
```

it crashes and shows

```
const debug$6 = debug_1$6.Debug.extend('debug-proxy-errors-plugin');
                                ^

TypeError: debug_1$6.Debug.extend is not a function
```

I tried different proxy libraries but it is not changing anything

Comment: "I tried different proxy libraries", what is the question here? Your project does not build when you're using a specific proxy package? Does it build with it? What is the exact library we're talking about here? Do you have a [repro]?